# Regex + Java - how to capture trailing numbers and everything else

Tags: java, regex

i'm trying to capture 2 things in a String "T3st12345"

I want to capture the trailing numbers ("12345") and also the name of the test "T3st".

This is what I have right now to match the trailing numbers with java's Matcher library:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]*$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("T3st12345");
```

but it returns "no match found".

How can I make this work for the trailing numbers and how do I capture the name of the test as well?

Comment: You have to call find or matches on matcher before it will find any matches. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex with 2 captured groups:

```
^(.*?)(\d+)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kyi9lP/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(.*?)`: Captured group #1 that matches zero of any character (lazy)
- `(\d+)`: Captured group #1 that matches one or more digits before End
- `$`: End

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\p{Alnum}+?)([0-9]*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("T3st12345");
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/SC7LHO)

The `(\\p{Alnum}+?)([0-9]*)` pattern  is used in the `.matches()` method (to require a full string match) and matches and captures into Group 1 one or more alphanumeric chars, as few as possible (`+?` is a lazy quantifier), and captures into Group 2  any zero or more digits.

Note that `\\p{Alnum}` can be replaced with a more explicit `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.